# Import CSV file using VBA

Tags: excel, csv, import, vba

I am a beginner in VBA. How can I import a csv file in excel? I know how to do it in VB6 but in VBA i tried to search a common dialogbox but i can't find it. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only check for some values and then close the file, you can simply open it as a new workbook like following:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=[YourPathHere], Delimiter:="[YourDelimeter]")
```

EDIT:
If you want to do that in a loop, let's imagine that your workbook names are located in cells "A1:A10" and you want to do data manipulation with each of the files

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim iCounter as Integer

For iCounter = 1 to 10
     Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Range("A" & iCounter).value,Delimiter:="[YourDelimiter]")
     //Do some manipulation with opened CSV file
Next iCounter
```

Comment: how can i import many csv file using a button like common dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\path\filename.csv"
```

or whatever drive you are using